# Remove elements from list based on a field of elements

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples where each tuple has two items; first item is a dictionary and second one is a string.

```
all_values = [
              ({'x1': 1, 'y1': 2}, 'str1'), 
              ({'x2': 1, 'y2': 2}, 'str2'), 
              ({'x3': 1, 'y3': 2}, 'str3'),
              ({'x4': 1, 'y4': 2}, 'str1'),
             ]
```

I want to remove duplicate data from list based on the second item of the tuple. I wrote this code, but I want to improve it:

```
flag = False
items = []
for index, item in enumerate(all_values):
    for j in range(0, index):
        if all_values[j][1] == all_values[index][1]:
            flag = True
    if not flag:
        items.append(item)
    flag = False
```

And get this:

```
items = [
         ({'x1': 1, 'y1': 2}, 'str1'), 
         ({'x2': 1, 'y2': 2}, 'str2'), 
         ({'x3': 1, 'y3': 2}, 'str3')
        ]
```

Any help?

BTW I tried to remove duplicate data using `list(set(all_values))` but I got error `unhashable type: dict`.

Comment: Second items in your tupple are str1, str2 and str3. They are unique already. Can you clarify? Also example input and expected output lists would be useful.

Comment: @Marcin it is a sample. In real world there is a big list which has some duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Use another list ('strings') to collect the second string items of the tuples. Thus, you will have a clear way to check if a current list item is a duplicate.

In the code below I added one duplicate list item (with 'str2' value) for demonstration purpose.

```
all_values = [
              ({'x1': 1, 'y1': 2}, 'str1'),
              ({'x2': 1, 'y2': 2}, 'str2'),
              ({'x5': 8, 'ab': 7}, 'str2'),
              ({'x3': 1, 'y3': 2}, 'str3')
             ]

strings = []
result = []
for value in all_values:
    if not value[1] in strings:
        strings.append(value[1])
        result.append(value)
```

The new non-duplicated list will be in 'result'.

Answer (score 0):

You could use following code

```
items = []
for item in all_values:
    if next((i for i in items if i[1] == item[1]), None) is None:
        items.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
items = []
[items.append(item) for item in all_values if item[1] not in [x[1] for x in items]]
print items
```

Answer (score 0):

The Object oriented approach is not shorter - but it's more intuitive as well as readable/maintainable (IMHO).

Start by creating an object that will mimic the tuple and will provide an additional `hash()` and `eq()` functions which will be used by `Set` later on to check the uniqueness of the objects.

The function `__repr__()` is declared for debugging purpose:

```
class tup(object):
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.t = t

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.t[1] == other.t[1]

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.t[1])

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(t)

# now you can declare:
all_values = [
              ({'x1': 1, 'y1': 2}, 'str1'), 
              ({'x2': 1, 'y2': 2}, 'str2'), 
              ({'x2': 1, 'y2': 2}, 'str2'), 
              ({'x3': 1, 'y3': 2}, 'str3'),
              ({'x3': 1, 'y3': 2}, 'str3')
             ]

#create your objects and put them in a list             
all_vals = []
map(lambda x: all_vals.append(Tup(x)), all_values)   


print all_vals  # [({'y1': 2, 'x1': 1}, 'str1'), ({'x2': 1, 'y2': 2}, 'str2'), ({'x2': 1, 'y2': 2}, 'str2'), ({'x3': 1, 'y3': 2}, 'str3'), ({'x3': 1, 'y3': 2}, 'str3')]  

# and use Set for uniqueness 
from sets import Set
print Set(all_vals) # Set([({'x3': 1, 'y3': 2}, 'str3'), ({'x3': 1, 'y3': 2}, 'str3'), ({'x3': 1, 'y3': 2}, 'str3')])
```

An alternative shorter version to those who feel that size matters ;)

```
res = []
for a in all_values:
    if a[1] not in map(lambda x: x[1], res):
        res.append(a)
print res
```

Comment: Seems like overkill, IMO. A shorter/local answer would also aid readability. Granted, your answer will be much more extensible.

Comment: @mogambo overkill ? maybe. The class definition is only 9 lines long. Loading the objects is another line, and using `Set` requires two lines. Half of the code you see here is printing, comments and the original structure. 12 lines of code is not too bad (again IMO)  ;)

Comment: True. But as compared to my code (serving as an example & shameless plug :P) which is 2 lines, a class defintion is definitely too much! Which *can't* be smaller than 4 lines. Either way, I'm not saying it's wrong just thought I'd put my 2c in :)

Comment: @mogambo here you go, 4 lines (not including the printing at the end)

Comment: But now you're not using your class definition, or am I just missing something? If you aren't can I take that you agreeing with me that a class definition is overkill ;)

Comment: @mogambo my bad, the wording is now corrected: "An *alternative* shorter..."

Answer (score 0):

If you're not concerned with the ordering, use a `dict`

```
formattedValues = {}
# Use with reveresed if you want the first duplicate to be kept
# Use without reveresed if you want the last duplicated
for v in reversed(allValues):
    formattedValues[ v[1] ] = v
```

If ordering *is* a concern, use `OrderedDict`

```
from collections import OrderedDict
formattedValues = OrderedDict()
for v in reversed(allValues):
    formattedValues[ v[1] ] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

[itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) has a function *unique_everseen*, it will return an iterator of the unique items in the passed in iterable according to the passed in key, if you want a list as a result just pass the result to list() but if theres lots of data it would be better to just iterate if you can to save memory.

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse
from operator import itemgetter

all_values = [
    ({'x1': 1, 'y1': 2}, 'str1'),
    ({'x2': 1, 'y2': 2}, 'str2'),
    ({'x5': 8, 'ab': 7}, 'str2'),
    ({'x3': 1, 'y3': 2}, 'str3')]


def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in ifilterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element

print list(unique_everseen(all_values, itemgetter(1)))
```

Output

```
[({'y1': 2, 'x1': 1}, 'str1'), ({'x2': 1, 'y2': 2}, 'str2'), ({'x3': 1, 'y3': 2}, 'str3')]
```